# display_name shows wrong field

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

I am trying to import an LDAP Contact to the android phone book
To do that i am creating a List of `ContentProviderOperation` out of a  like this:

```kotlin
 fun transformSearchEntryToAndroidEntry(entry: SearchResultEntry)
            : ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> = try {
        val providerOpList = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()
        providerOpList.apply {
            add(
                ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                        LDAPConfig.ACCOUNT_NAME
                    )
                    .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                        LDAPConfig.ACCOUNT_TYPE
                    )
                    .build()
            )
            entry.attributes.forEach { contact ->
                when (contact.name.toString()) {
                    "cn" -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Adding display name: ${contact.value}")
                        add(
                            ContentProviderOperation
                                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                .withValue(
                                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                    CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                )
                                .withValue(
                                    CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    contact.value
                                )
                                .build()
                        )
                    }

                    "objectClass" -> add(
                        createStandardOperation(
                            contact.name,
                            contact.values.toList().toString()
                        )
                    )

                    else -> add(createStandardOperation(contact.name, contact.value))
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Provider List: $providerOpList")
        providerOpList
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        ArrayList()
    }
```

The Problem is that not when `cn` is triggered, it makes this:

```
ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@668e696, data1=Erwin Erstie}),
```

But it shows not the name of this, it takes the name of the first entry of the ArrayList. That means in the Android Phonebook App appears the value of `objectClass`

This is the whole entry for the Android phone book:

```
[
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts values={account_name=LDAP, account_type=com.example.account.ldap}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@5ec51b1, data1=objectClass, data2=[top, inetOrgPerson, posixAccount, shadowAccount]}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@668e696, data1=Erwin Erstie}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@ef01217, data1=sn, data2=Erstie}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@684e604, data1=uid, data2=e.erstie}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@fc357ed, data1=uidNumber, data2=10000}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@944d622, data1=gidNumber, data2=10000}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@bd9b8b3, data1=homeDirectory, data2=/home/e.erstie}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@f6c5e70, data1=loginShell, data2=/bin/bash}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@8a85e9, data1=userPassword, data2=passwort}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@afe326e, data1=shadowLastChange, data2=0}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@ad2d0f, data1=shadowMax, data2=0}), 
  ContentProviderOperation(type=insert uri=content://com.android.contacts/data values={mimetype=vnd.android.cursor.item/name, raw_contact_id=android.content.ContentProviderOperation$BackReference@610f19c, data1=shadowWarning, data2=0})]
```

Does anyone know whats going wrong?

By the way, thats the `createStandardOperation()`

```kotlin
    private fun createStandardOperation(title: String, source: String): ContentProviderOperation =
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            )
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, title)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, source)
            .build()
```